# Gradle - How to detect --debug flag from command line?

Tags: gradle

I have a task in which I am executing a command. And I need to change which parameters are passed to the command depending on whether I do `./gradlew --debug myTask` or `./gradlew myTask`.

I thought that it would be as simple as doing: `project.logger.isEnabled(LogLevel.DEBUG)`, but this returns false even when `--debug` is passed to Gradle.

-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-

It seems that you are both correct. I was making an invalid assumption that the main Gradle process would pass its debug flag information to the tooling API, which turned out to be incorrect. The issue was that I needed to pass an additional `--debug` flag to the tooling API process.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use

`if (project.gradle.startParameter.logLevel.name() == 'DEBUG')`

@see [StartParameter.getLogLevel()](https://docs.gradle.org/3.4.1/javadoc/org/gradle/StartParameter.html#getLogLevel%28%29)

Comment: Why not simply `logLevel == LogLevel.DEBUG`?

Comment: Because you'd need to import the class, or fully qualify the class name

Answer (score 3):

The following `build.gradle` works just fine:

```
println "LOL ${logger.isDebugEnabled()}"
```

Try running just `gradle` and `gradle -d` or `gradle --debug`

Comment: I will give it a shot. I was trying a bunch of different things. With and without project, etc. Not sure if it makes a difference, but I am doing this not from build.gradle, but rather in a task extending DefaultTask.

Comment: @kurzweil4 it possibly makes a difference - I mean script evaluation may play a role here.

Comment: You are both right, but Lance's answer is more specific. Thank you for the response!