# How to check if tests are started in debug-mode from Intellij inside Gradle-Script

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, gradle

Inside my Gradle-script I want to check if the tests are started in debug mode by Intellij Idea.

I've already tried the following:

- [`Test#getDebug()`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test:debug) always returns false
- [`ManagementFactory#getRuntimeMXBean()...`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6865049/) returns the same parameters for run and debug executions (because Gradle itself is not startet in debug mode only the test)
- [detect --debug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43357592/gradle-how-to-detect-debug-flag-from-command-line) always returns false

How can I find out if Intellij started the tests in debug mode?

It could be something like detecting if `--debug-jvm` isset, but as of now, I cannot find the process which starts the tasks. (I've tried something like `ps aux | grep test` which got me no results)

Comment: I solved this by adding a VM option `-Didea` to Gradle configuration in IntelliJ (Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle -> Gradle VM options). Then in Gradle script, there is a condition `boolean idea2017 = System.getProperty('idea') != null`

Comment: @VáclavKužel yeah with this it would be possible to check if gradle was executed from intellij but not if tests were executed in debug mode.